# IEEE conference style on Greek symbols

Tags: conference, writing-style, ieee

I'm preparing my paper for submission to an IEEE conference. The style guide is [here (zip file)](https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/conferences/IEEEtranBST2.zip).
Under equations, the conference style guide says:
"you may use the solidus (/), the exp function, or appropriate exponents. Italicize Roman symbols for quantities and variables, but not Greek symbols." Then proceeds to give an example with `\gamma` which is a Greek letter. Does anyone know if Greek letters are allowed or not?

[image: IEEE conference guide on equations]

Comment: That only says not to italicize greek letters.

Comment: Related if not duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/159594/20058, see my answer: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/159596/20058

Comment: If you use LaTeX this is easy. See the second answer here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219975/how-to-get-non-italic-greek-symbols-with-ams-packages

Comment: Thanks, looks like I've mis-interpreted. I'm using overleaf and there's no `unicode-math`, so I've gone with `upgreek` even though I don't really like prefixing everything with `up`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use Greek letters.

But do not italicize them.

Here is an example of a random IEEE Conference [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8857230) that displays a formula in which Greek letters are not italicized, while other letters are:

[image]

Note that the psi (ψ) and pi (π) are not italicized, but *t* and *e* are.

Comment: Thanks, I've mis-interpreted. I've switched over to `upgreek`.